# jquery add listener to elements

Tags: jquery, audio, bind

I need some help to add and play some sounds, I have this code for making some audio elements:

```
        $.each(mySounds, function(i){
            var SoundID = 'sound_'+i;
            $("<audio></audio>").attr({ 
                'id': SoundID,
                'src':'wav/'+mySounds[i], 
                'volume':1,
        }).appendTo('body');
```

Wich produces this on the DOM:

```
<audio id="mySound_0" src="audio0.wav" volume="1"></audio>
<audio id="mySound_1" src="audio1.wav" volume="1"></audio>
```

How I can add a listener to play the sound when call a function?

I've tried this without success:

```
    $.each(mySounds, function(i){
        var SoundID = 'sound_'+i;
        $("<audio></audio>").attr({ 
            'id': SoundID,
            'src':mySounds[i], 
            'volume':1,
    }).appendTo('body').bind('playSound', function(){
            this.play();
        });
```

and call like this:

```
$('#sound_1').playSound();
```

Any ideas how to make work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $.each(mySounds, function(i){
        var SoundID = 'sound_'+i;
        $("<audio></audio>",{ 
            'id': SoundID,
            'src':'wav/'+mySounds[i], 
            'volume':1,
    }).appendTo('body').on('playSound', function(){
            this.play();
        });
```

Use Trigger for custom events

```
$('#sound_1').trigger('playSound');
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding an event doesn't create a new method for you to execute, you need to instead trigger the event.

```
$('#sound_1').trigger('playSound')
```